# Preventing duplicate objects from being added to array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am building a little shop for a client and storing the information as an array of objects. But I want to ensure that I am not creating "duplicate" objects. I have seen similar solutions, but perhaps it is my "newness" to coding preventing me from getting the gist of them to implement in my own code, so I'd like some advice specific to what I have done.

I have tried putting my code in an if look, and if no "part", my variable looking for part number, exists in the code, then add the part, and could not get it to function.

Here is the function I am working on:

```
   function submitButton(something) {
     window.scroll(0, 0);
     cartData = ($(this).attr("data").split(','));

     arrObj.push({
       part: cartData[0],
       description: cartData[1]
     });

   }
```

arrObj is defined as a global variable, and is what I am working with here, with a "part" and a "description", which is the data I am trying to save from elsewhere and output to my "#cart". I have that part working, I just want to ensure that the user cannot add the same item twice. (or more times.)

Sorry if my code is shoddy or I look ignorant; I am currently a student trying to figure these things out so most of JS and Jquery is completely new to me. Thank you.

Comment: You need `if (!arrObj.some(item => item.part == cardData[0]) arrObj.push(...)` (Array#some tests whether the function returns true for any element)

Comment: Can I buy two identical parts in your store?

Comment: Georg: you can, but that is handled elsewhere and not by using data. All this does is send an email back so I will have a different POST field where quantity will be specified, and that information emailed to my client. It does not need to affect the data as it exists.

Comment: @JoelPeterson so did the answer fromChris G solve you the problem...

Comment: I hope this isn't a real client and a real shop. 20 years ago something like this wasn't a big deal, but nowadays you'll have that store hacked and defrauded in no time.

Comment: I'm not sure about the rest of your code but if checking for duplicity is a must I would go with a Map and store the ID (or whatever unique identifier you have) as the key and the Object as the value. Also, note that this kind of thing should be done server-side, at the client-side stuff you write is just considered for convenience.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [`proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) and use `Map` to hold and access values, something like this

```js
let cart =  new Map([{ id: 1, title: "Dog toy" }, { id: 2, title: "Best of Stackoverflow 2018" }].map(v=>[v.id,v]));

let handler = {
  set: function(target,prop, value, reciver){
     if(target.has(+prop)){
      console.log('already available')
     } else{
      target.set(prop,value)
     }
  },
  get: function(target,prop){
    return target.get(prop)
  }
}

let proxied = new Proxy(cart, handler)

proxied['1'] = {id:1,title:'Dog toy'}
proxied['3'] = {id:3,title:'Dog toy new value'}

console.log(proxied['3'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the 'part' property is unique on every cartData, I did checking only based on it.

```
  function submitButton(something) {
     window.scroll(0, 0);
     cartData = ($(this).attr("data").split(','));

     if(!isDuplicate(cartData))
     arrObj.push({
       part: cartData[0],
       description: cartData[1]
     });

   }

   const isDuplicate = (arr) => {
     for(obj of arrObj){
       if(arr[0] === obj.part) 
         return true;
     }

     return false;
   }
```

If you want to do the checking on both 'part' and 'description' properties, you may replace the if statement with `if(arr[0] === obj.part && arr[1] === obj.description)`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for their suggestions. Using this and help from a friend, this is the solution that worked:

```
function submitButton(something) {
  window.scroll(0,0);
  cartData = ($(this).attr("data").split(','));

let cartObj = {
  part: cartData[0],
  description: cartData[1],
  quantity: 1
}

match = false
arrObj.forEach(function(cartObject){
  if (cartObject.part == cartData[0]) {
  match = true;
}
})
console.log(arrObj);
if (!match) { 
    arrObj.push(cartObj); 
    }
```

Comment: This is much more complicated than using .some(), look at my response.

Answer (score -1):

Okay, you have multiple possible approaches to this. All of them need you to specify some kind of identifier on the items which the user can add. Usually, this is just an ID integer.

So, if you have that integer you can do the following check to make sure it's not in the array of objects:

```js
let cart =  [{ id: 1, title: "Dog toy" }, { id: 2, title: "Best of Stackoverflow 2018" }];

function isInCart(id) {
  return cart.some(obj => obj.id === id);
}

console.log(isInCart(1));
console.log(isInCart(3));
```

Another approach is saving the items by their id in an object:

```js
let cart = { 1: { title: "Dog toy" }, 2: { title: "Best of Stackoverflow 2018" } };

function isInCart(id) {
  if(cart[id]) return true;
  
  return false;
}
```

Comment: `return` in `forEach` is useless. Does not return to outer function

Comment: No. Not in arrow function

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `indexOf` to check if the object exists, for example:

```
var beasts = ['ant', 'bison', 'camel', 'duck', 'bison'];

console.log(beasts.indexOf('aaa'));
// expected output: -1
```

Comment: But OP is not working with array of primitives. Can't use `indexOf()` for different object references even if all their properties and values are the same